# two separate menus into one responsive drop down when on mobile device

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

i have two completely seperate menus in the head of my site,

there is a good reason for this as both menus are styled completely different and have different links etc;

for eg:

```
<div class="menu1">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">three</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="menu2">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">drop 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">drop 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href="">drop 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

is there a way a can combine both of the navigations in a full width style toggle drop down when the device width is less the 768.

so it will turn it to:

```
<div class="menus combined">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="">three</a></li>
  <li><a href="">drop 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">drop 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href="">drop 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated!

thank you!

Comment: Hi did you find a resolution for this? I also need the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

u can also use

```
<div class="menus combined">
 <ul>
 <select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>drop 1</option>
    <option>sub 1</option>
    <option>drop 2</option>
    <option>sub 2</option>
    <option>drop 3</option>
    <option>sub 3</option>
    <option>one</option>
 </select>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML of the page can't be changed with CSS media queries, but you can through JavaScript.

[Take a look at this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmVfK) to see how it combines the 2 menus if the document width is 768px or narrower.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

// Get the width of the body:
var bodyWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

if (bodyWidth <= 768) {
    // Change the class of the first menu:
    $('.menu1').attr('class', 'menus combined'); 

    // Add in the items from the second menu into the first:
    $('.menus.combined ul').append($('.menu2 ul').html());        
}

});
```

You might also want to add a resize event listener to run the code as the browser is resized, otherwise it only runs when the page is first loaded.

Comment: Will `menu2 ul` disappear from its original place when appended, or should it be removed using JavaScript as well?

Comment: `menu2 ul` will remain there, so you might want to then remove it with `$('.menu2 ul').remove();`